# Split text buffer text according to tags python gtk

Tags: python, tags, split, gtk, pygtk

i have a textview with a text buffer.
i have added many tags to the text buffer with

```
buffer.get_tag_table().add(tag)
```

So i was wondering if there was a way to get all the text from the text view and split it according to the tag it has

im using gtk 2 btw

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the iterator at beginning of buffer and move through the buffer with `it.forward_to_tag_toggle()`. At each point, `it.get_tags()` will give you a list of tags that apply to the current chunk of text, and `buf.get_text(it, next_it)` will give you the text itself:

```
def split(buf):
    it = buf.get_start_iter()
    while not it.is_end():
        nextpos = it.copy()
        nextpos.forward_to_tag_toggle(None)
        yield buf.get_text(it, nextpos), it.get_tags()
        it = nextpos
```